# Shell script can't find other files when launched on login (Debian Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi

So I have a script that is launched on login via rc.local. The script calls a few other scripts to be launched and ran. However the console says that the file and/or directories could not be found. When I run the script manually after the login it works just fine. I have even tried to add a small delay so that I know that the system logged in. Any idea why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my answer is a bit vague but from what I understand is that the scripts require to be run via admin privileges. Let me elaborate, when the system starts it runs a set of specific scripts and this differs from distro to distro. Therefore, I'd check `~/.bashrc` `/etc/profile.d`and most **importantly** `~/.bash_login`. See what you can do there. Personally I added it here `~/.config/autostart` worked fine. Don't forget to create a `.desktop` file.

**Hope this helps**